# How connect columns based on the value of one field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table looks like this:

```
    |__name___|value__|
    |__James__|___6___|
    |__Jerry__|___5___|
    |__Jerry__|___4___|
    |__James__|___3___|
    |__James__|___2___|
    |__James__|___2___|
```

and I need to get from first table output like :

```
    |_name____|value_|
    |  James  |   2  |
    |         |   2  |
    |         |   3  |
    |_________|___6__|
    |  Jerry  |   4  |
    |_________|___5__|
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should do that in your program logic and not in SQL directly

Comment: I can't :/ I need to send the output to reporting program, which unfortunately can't do nothing special like logic sort etc

Answer (score 1):

this also works. It stores the last record in @old_name and compare it

```
  SELECT
    IF(name = @old_name ,'',(@old_name := name)) AS name
    ,value 
    FROM mytable
    ,(SELECT @old_name:='')AS tmp
  ORDER BY name,value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
           value = (SELECT MIN(value) FROM table t WHERE t.name = name)
       THEN name
       ELSE ''
       END AS name, value
FROM table
ORDER BY name ASC, value ASC
```

Comment: Why would a tie in `value` for a given `name` have any effect on the desired output?

Comment: Never mind.  Then the `name` would print twice.  Good catch, George.

Comment: Yes if this tie exists for the case of `MIN(value)` like in `('James', 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
|_name____|value_|
|  James  |   2  |
|  James  |   2  |
|  James  |   3  |
|  James  |   6  |
|  Jerry  |   4  |
|  Jerry  |___5__|
```

only like this (`select * from $table_name order by name;`),
cant like this:

```
    |_name____|value_|
    |  James  |   2  |
    |         |   2  |
    |         |   3  |
    |_________|___6__|
    |  Jerry  |   4  |
    |_________|___5__|
```

Answer (score 0):

Bernd Buffen.. Your Select return something like that :/ :

```
|_name____|value_|
|_________|   2  |
|_________|   2  |
|_________|   3  |
|_________|   4  |
|__James__|   5  |
|__Jerry__|___6__|
```